# Не могу понять как работают массивы в ардуино

Tags: c++, arduino

Пишу на ардуинке прогу и столкнулся с таким затруднением:

```
String messenge;
for (int i=1; i <= 10; i++){
messenge += String(dht_i.readHumidity());
delay(50);
}
```

Смысл в том, что у меня есть 10 переменных с названиями:

```
dht_1
dht_2
dht_3
....
dht_10
```

И цикл должен менять i на 1,2,3....
Но программа ругается, мол нет переменой dht_i.
Это логично да, программа права.
Вот собственно хочу спросить совета более опытных юзеров, ибо в интернете особо ничего не нагуглил.
Кто нибудь может посоветовать как это лучше реализовать?
Спасибо

Comment: Если на шарпе то так:  `$"dht_{i}"`. В ардуино не работал.

Comment: использовать массив?

Comment: Лучше использовать массив.

Comment: Дичь написал на самом деле. Единственный вариант завести класс и вытягивать значение полей через рефлексию.

Comment: У вас получается 10 датчиков влажности? Каждый сидит на своем пине?

Comment: Да, 2,3 пин - GSM модуль.
А пины с 4 по 13 ( цифровые ) - датчики.

Comment: А что, на ардуино массивов нет?...

Comment: я пробовал, но как то не получилось. Можно пример?

Comment: мой ответ посмотри :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DHT dht[10];
String message;
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
   message += String(dht[i].readHumidity());
   delay(50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дам ответ  с примером применения массивов

```
// Массив контактов светодиодов 
int leds[] = {13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4}
// количество загоревшихся светодиодов 
int n =0;

void setup(){
     // настроить выводы ардуики на "ВЫХОД"
     for (int i=0; i<10; i=i+1){
          pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
     }
}

void loop() {
   // выключить n светодиодов
   for (int i =0; i<10; i=i+1){
     if(i<n)
       {digitalWrite(leds[i], HIGH);}
     else 
       {digitalWrite(leds[i], LOW);}
   }

    // изменить n - приращение на 1
    // остаток от деления на 11 (после 10 -> 0)
    n = (n+1)%11; // n работает так : 0->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->10->0...
}
```

Замете если бы мне пришлось объявлять светодиоды без массивов то пришлось бы писать так :

```
void setup(){
      pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
```

а вышло так :3

```
void setup(){
     // настроить выводы ардуинки на "ВЫХОД"
     for (int i=0; i<10; i=i+1){
          pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
     }
}
```

**По сути массив позволяет сэкономить количество введенных букв и циферок.**

Так же немного теории:

Объявление массива без его инициализации:

> ```
> int leds[10]; // массив из 10 элементов типа int
> ```

Можно объявить массив без без непосредственного указания размера . Компилятор считает количество элементов и создаст массив соответствующего размера:

> ```
> int leds[] = {13,12,11,10,,9,8,7,6,5,4};
> ```

Можно одновременно инициализировать и указать размер вашего массива:

> ```
> int leds[10] = {13,12,11,10,,9,8,7,6,5,4};
> ```

*Всё на ваше усмотрение :3*